# Marshal C# Class Array as Struct Array To C

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, struct, marshalling

Here is my code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Foo
{
  UInt32 StartAddr;
  UInt32 Type;
}


[DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint="_MyFunc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern unsafe IntPtr MyFunc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Foo[] Foos);


List<Foo> Foos = new List<Foo>();
Foo1 = new Foo();
Foo1.StartAddr = 1;
Foo1.Type = 2;
Foos.Add(Foo1);
MyFunc(Foos.ToArray());
```

In the C-based DLL I print out the value of Foos[0].StartAddr and Foos[0].Type. This works great.

Now I want to add a parameterless constructor to the struct which means I have to switch to a class. By only changing the C# declaration from "struct" to "class" results in corrupted values being passed to the C-based DLL.

I believe this should work but I presume I am missing a step. How can I pass an array of C# classes as a array of structs to C code?

Thanks! Andy

Comment: Yes, won't work.  The array will be marshaled as Foo** instead of Foo*.  An array of pointers to Foo.  No clean workaround either, manual marshaling is very ugly here.  Don't do this if you can't change the C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need default item in your struct you can add static property to it

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct Foo
    {
      UInt32 StartAddr;
      UInt32 Type;

      public static Foo Default
      {
          get 
          {
               Foo result = new Foo();
               result.StartAddr = 200;
               result.Type = 10;
               return result;
          }
      }
    }
```

And when you need to create new `Foo` struct just call `Foo.Default`